# Perform Segue from a custom Button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created a custom button to include in the button the information I need:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {   
   var urlString: String?
   var documentType: String?
   var requestEntity: String?
   var requestSortBy: [NSSortDescriptor]?
   var requestPredicate: NSPredicate?
}
```

When I create the cells in the collectionView (embedded in a tableView) I include the information in my custom button, called `documentTypeButton`. And also the target for executing the function `HomeTableViewController.documentTypeButtonTapped(_:)` to perform the segue.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let languageSelected = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "language") as! String

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "allDocumentsItemCell", for: indexPath) as! AllDocumentsCollectionViewCell

    cell.documentTypeButton.documentType = Catalog.sharedInstance.allSections[allDocumentsSection!].singleItems[indexPath.row].name
    cell.documentTypeButton.requestEntity = Catalog.sharedInstance.allSections[allDocumentsSection!].singleItems[indexPath.row].entityName
    cell.documentTypeButton.requestSortBy = Catalog.sharedInstance.allSections[allDocumentsSection!].singleItems[indexPath.row].sortBy
    cell.documentTypeButton.requestPredicate = Catalog.sharedInstance.allSections[allDocumentsSection!].singleItems[indexPath.row].predicate
    cell.documentTypeButton.addTarget(nil, action: #selector(HomeTableViewController.documentTypeButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


    return cell

}
```

And the, in the `HomeTableViewController` I have the function to execute when touching inside the button:

```
@objc func documentTypeButtonTapped(_ sender: CustomButton) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDocumentList", sender: CustomButton())
    print(sender.documentType)
    print(sender.requestEntity)

}

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: CustomButton) {

    let languageSelected = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "language") as! String

    if let destination = segue.destination as? DocumentListTableViewController {

        destination.titlePassed = sender.documentType!.localized(lang: languageSelected)
        destination.requestedEntity = sender.requestEntity
        destination.requestedSortBy = sender.requestSortBy
        destination.requestedPredicate = sender.requestPredicate

    }

}
```

The print statements above work well and print the information. And the segue goes to the `DocumentListTableViewController`.

In the `viewDidLoad` of the `DocumentListTableViewController` I added the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(titlePassed)
    print(requestedEntity)

}
```

And the two print statements print `nil`.

I guess the problem should be in the `prepareForSegue`, maybe with the sender... I don't know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try to pass `sender` parameter in `performSegue()` method like this:

```
@objc func documentTypeButtonTapped(_ sender: CustomButton) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDocumentList", sender: sender)
    print(sender.documentType)
    print(sender.requestEntity)

}
```

Problem is that you are instantiating new object of type CustomButton() instead passing `sender`.

Comment: Still returns nil for the two print statements in the DocumentListTableViewController

Comment: Try to use breakpoint if assign statements in prepare method are invoked and have proper data.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you pass a new (empty) instance of `CustomButton` in the `performSegue` call rather than the `sender` of the action.

But your design to create a custom button as data container is still worse. **Don't do that**. It's horrible.

There is a much easier and more efficient solution:

In `AllDocumentsCollectionViewCell` create a callback closure

```
var callback : (()->Void)?
```

and an `IBAction` and connect it to the button, the callback is called when the button is tapped.

```
@IBAction func documentTypeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    callback?()
}
```

In `HomeTableViewController` assign a closure to the callback, perform the segue in there and pass the item of the data source array.

But the way calling `UserDefaults().value(` in each call of `collectionView` and getting the **same** item for index path 4 times is very very inefficient. And never use `value(forKey`. There is `string(forKey` in `UserDefaults`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let languageSelected = UserDefaults().string(forKey: "language")! 

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "allDocumentsItemCell", for: indexPath) as! AllDocumentsCollectionViewCell
    cell.callback {
         let item = Catalog.sharedInstance.allSections[allDocumentsSection!].singleItems[indexPath.row]
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDocumentList", sender: item)
    }
    return cell

}
```

In `prepare(for` get the data source item (I have no idea what type it is) and retrieve the information from there. You can even pass the entire item to the destination view controller.

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: CustomButton) {

    let languageSelected = UserDefaults().string(forKey: "language")! 

    if let destination = segue.destination as? DocumentListTableViewController {
        let item = sender as! WhatEverTheTypeIs // change this to the real type
        destination.titlePassed = item.name.localized(lang: languageSelected)
        destination.requestedEntity = item.entityName
        destination.requestedSortBy = item.sortBy
        destination.requestedPredicate = item.predicate

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. When you say "In HomeTableViewController assign a closure to the callback, perform the segue in there and pass the item of the data source array." I have no idea about how to do that. I have been searching but it is difficult for me to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

In your performSegue call your are sending a new instance of `CustomButton`

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDocumentList", sender: CustomButton())
```

So its parameters are going to be nil in the next view controller, you need to send the sender instead.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDocumentList", sender: sender)
```

You need to override `prepareForSegue` for it to be called, no need to change to its signature, you could write it like this instead:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let languageSelected = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "language") as! String

    if let destination = segue.destination as? DocumentListTableViewController {

        let myCustomButton = sender as! CustomButton

        destination.titlePassed = myCustomButton.documentType!.localized(lang: languageSelected)
        destination.requestedEntity = myCustomButton.requestEntity
        destination.requestedSortBy = myCustomButton.requestSortBy
        destination.requestedPredicate = myCustomButton.requestPredicate

    }
}
```